# Matlab Class Method Error

Tags: matlab, constructor

I'm new to matlab classes and have just gone through a couple tutorials and now am trying to make one.  In my methods section however, I'm having trouble with what I've been trying to do.  The object should only need a single piece of info to construct the remaining properties which I will pass as input to the constructor.  I was then thinking that I should be able to call two more functions in the methods section to fill in the remaining properties... see pseudocode below...

```
methods
    function obj=myConstructor(input)
        obj.property1=input;
        getProperty2(obj);
        getProperty3(obj);
    end

    function getProperty2(obj)
        obj.property2 = do something and save in property2...
    end

    function getProperty3(obj)
        obj.property3 = do something and save in property3...
    end

end
```

However, when I try and run this, neither property 2 or 3 are assigned... only the value that I pass to the constructor.  Any help/ideas on how to accomplish the initialization would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `get` methods are usually used to retrieve (i.e. get) the value of a property of an object. Not to calculate something.

Next, the MATLAB object model has two different kinds: value objects and handle objects. The distinction is important, but as you don't mention any, I will assume you are using value objects. The behavior for handle objects is totally different.

In contrast to e.g. Java and most other languages, you need to return the changed object. So in MATLAB this would be something like:

```
classdef MyClass
    properties
        p1, p2, p3;
    end
    methods
       function obj = MyClass(input)
          obj.p1 = input;
          obj = obj.calculateP2(input);
          obj = obj.calculateP3(input);
       end
       function obj = calculateP2(obj, input)
          obj.p2 = someLengthyCalculation(input);
       end
       function obj = calculateP3(obj, input)
          obj.p3 = someOtherLengthyCalculation(input);
       end
    end
end
```

This can be made more clean, as most likely the `calculateP?` methods belong better as private static methods. This all depends on how much you want to pass to these methods.

Comment: This might not be the best place to ask, but I don't want to start a new question:
Why is it not possible to use `obj = calculateP2(input);` instead of `obj = obj.calculateP2(input);`? Why does this result in an error (provided no other function `calculateP2` exists on the MATLAB path)? Why doesn't the constructor know about class methods, but must you specify the method using obj.method() notation? And is there any preference for either of the following notations? `obj = obj.calculateP2(input);` or `obj = MyClass.calculateP2(input);`?

Comment: @Erik: I think the current syntax is quite explicit and hence the least error-prone (i.e. the least chance you will need to know what happens behind the scenes: precedence rules, etc.). Note also that `MyClass.calculateP2(input)` is also not valid: this is how you call static functions! If you want to call a (non-static) method, there are two possibilities: `obj.method(args)` or `method(obj, args)`. I prefer the former, but sometimes the latter is useful to provide standard interfaces, e.g. `plot(obj)`. For more info, please just open the chat or a question :-)